# How can i import an obj model with javaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a rendering engine with javaFX and I want to import an obj model, but I have this error: ObjModelImporter read(URL url): url is null!

I don't know where this error comes from !

Anyone have an idea ?

There is the code to import the model :

```
ObjModelImporter objImporter = new ObjModelImporter();
        try{
            URL modelUrl = this.getClass().getResource("assets/David.obj");
            objImporter.read(modelUrl);
        }catch(ImportException e){
            System.out.println("Pas d'url");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        MeshView[] meshViews = objImporter.getImport();
        Group David = new Group(meshViews);

       Scene scene = new Scene(David, 600, 600, true);
       scene.setCamera(camera);
       scene.setFill(Color.GREY);


      primaryStage.setTitle("DavidTest");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra Edited !

Comment: And is `assets/David.obj` the correct _relative_ name based on the location of `this.getClass()`? If not, use an absolute name: `/assets/David.obj`.

Comment: The code posted is not mre. Please follow the link posted.